# What is strange in this puzzle?

Tags: riddle, story

I entered a room where there was no one around me so I waited for years and years for my friend to enter. My friend had sent me to this room for a reason I do not know. As years began to pass I noticed that there was a string hanging on me. Suddenly I heard a noise and hoped it would be my friend. Then I saw 2 gray figures coming towards me and then they started attacking me. I saw they had a string hanging on top of them. At that same moment I looked through the window and saw giant people looking at me. The grey figures left and I saw my family there with me and at that moment I knew this is real. The question was where am I and why are there giant people looking at me?

Comment: "What is strange about this puzzle?" "I entered a room [and] waited *years and years*." hmmmmmmmm...

Comment: This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I find it strange that the entire question contains no commas. I think that the real answer is likely less meta.

Comment: Given the answer you have accepted can you explain why you enter a room with nobody around and wait for years for your friend to enter? And why your friend had sent you to the room? And indeed what the two grey figures that attack you are and so on. I would think that maybe the two gray figures are others in the puppet show but I wouldn't expect a puppet to have been isolated in the location of the show until it starts for years. It feels like I can make individual parts fit the question/answer but not all of it at the same time. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> You are a puppet!

Reason:

> The giant people are human beings. They appear big to you because you are small. Also, the string attached to you means that you are a puppet. The gray figures might be other puppets.

Comment: Cool answer, but why do humans have a string on top of them? What is it? A top-knot?

Comment: I am saying that they are not humans, but rather puppets!

Comment: That's what I thought after reading this puzzle. Nice job!

Comment: I'm not sure I get how this corresponds to the first few sentences (entering a room and waiting for years and years).

Answer (score 9):

You are

> crazy. (What is strange in this puzzle?) *You are*.

The string hanging on you is a

> wire. It attaches to the electrodes.

The strings hanging on them is

> from their doctors masks.

At the moment

> that they (attacked you) flipped the switch, you began having that delusion about the giant people again. Once the procedure was complete, the delusion had passed and you were welcomed back to **real**ity by your loving family.

The answer:

> *Where am I?* You are in a psychiatric ward.
> *Why are giant people looking at me?* Refer to, *where am I*.

Comment: This is a really nice idea!

Comment: This creeps me out but does fit.

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> A frozen embryo being fertilized perhaps?  The window could be the microscope lens / test tube?  Strings are the sperm being injected into you to fertilize you intra-embryo i.e. via needle and micro-tweezers (the gray things)?  Things get real because you now exist as an arguably human entity?  People looking at you are your parents possibly, and or doctors perhaps?

Strange part is:

> Why you've got a string attached in the first place ...

My answers seems too literal however ...